# How can I save an Excel backup in SharePoint?

Tags: vba, sharepoint

How can I save an Excel backup in SharePoint?
To access the share point folder I need a username and password.
Attached capture of the code and the error that jumps to me.

I leave the code here below.

```
       ServerShare = "https://mycom.sharepoint.com/sites/Backupvehculo/Shared%20Documents/General/Copia/"
       UserName = "xxxx"
       password = "xxxx"

       Set NetworkObject = CreateObject("WScript.Network")

       NetworkObject.MapNetworkDrive "", ServerShare, False, UserName, password

nombrearchivo = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, Len(ThisWorkbook.Name) - 5) & VBA.Format(VBA.Now, "_dd-mm-yyyy-hh:mm:ss")
        
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:= _
        "https://mycom.sharepoint.com/sites/Backupvehculo/Shared%20Documents/General/Copia/" & nombrearchivo & ".xlsm" _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
        

    'Set FSO = Nothing
    Set NetworkObject = Nothing
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

I did this almost 10 years ago. Not sure it still works, but you can try it.

```
Sub OpenAndCloseWBFromSharePointFolder()

'If nobody has the file checked out
If Workbooks.CanCheckOut("http://excel-pc:43231/Shared Documents/ExcelList.xlsb") = True Then
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Open the file on the SharePoint server
Workbooks.Open Filename:="http://excel-pc:43231/Shared Documents/ExcelList.xlsb", UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever

'Close the workbook
Workbooks("ExcelList.xlsb").Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Else
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Open the File to check if you already have it checked out
Workbooks.Open Filename:="http://excel-pc:43231/Shared Documents/ExcelList.xlsb", UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever

'See if doc can be checked in
If Application.Workbooks("ExcelList.xlsb").CanCheckIn Then

'Check In, Save and Close
Application.Workbooks("ExcelList.xlsb").CheckIn SaveChanges:=True, Comments:="Checked-In before Delete"

'Open the file again
Workbooks.Open Filename:="http://excel-pc:43231/Shared Documents/ExcelList.xlsb"

'Close the workbook
Workbooks("ExcelList.xlsb").Close
End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Primero quería darte las gracias por contestarme.
Entiendo tu código, pero el problema que tengo es que es una carpeta compartida y tengo que introducir usuario y contraseña para poder acceder a ella.